# Xcode 6 automatically adds unsupported entitlements on compile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an app in the Mac App Store, that's been built using the following entitlements for over a year without any issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.example.myapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now, when I try to upload my first build using Xcode 6 I got some strange errors from Itunes Connect. What it says is basically:

```
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature
contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X; this
may happen if your Mac OS X project was ported from iOS. Please check your
Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any
unneeded entitlements.

Specifically, value "development" for key "com.apple.developer.aps-environment" is not supported.
Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment" is not supported.
```

The thing is, I can not find any reference to these entitlements inside my project. But when I inspect the "Binary and Entitlements" window in the orgnizer I see that Xcode has added these to my requested entitlements.

Where do the entitlements come from and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same problem with XCode inserting the `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` key when it's not valid.

Answer (score 3):

> Specifically, value "development" for key "com.apple.developer.aps-environment" is not supported.

This indicates that you are using a provisioning profile that is set up for "development". For push notifications to work you need to use a "distribution" provisioning profile. You can use Ad Hoc if you aren't ready to distribute to the app store.

You did say it's been over a year. Perhaps you had the correct provisioning profile and it has now expired.

> Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment" is not supported.

There are some changes to iCloud with Yosemite. You may need to edit your App ID in the developer portal and make sure your settings are compatible with the version of OS X you are targeting. After editing the App ID you will need to generate a new provisioning profile for that App ID.

You can also find and edit most of the entitlements in Xcode 6 by selecting the project in the project navigator then selecting the target and go to the "Capabilities" tab.

Comment: The weird thing is that push notifications are not even active for my app id or the provisioning profile I use to sign the app. I did regenerate all certificates and recreated the Entitlements file, but I still got the same issues. In the end I actually downloaded Xcode 5 and was able to sign the application properly.

Comment: the problem is that if your use the 'capabilities'  tag to adjust your iCloud settings it is specifically Xcode 6 that then adds the "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment" entitlement which it later claims is not supported!

Comment: Same problem here! Xcode adds game-center entitlement and get-task-allow, saying on submit phase that get-task-allow not supported for OS X